# child entity of type cannot be updated independent of its parent

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am using Silverlight + WCF RIA.

Domain model:

```
public partial class Card
{        
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }  

    [Display()]
    [Include]
    [Composition]
    public IList<CardAttributesValue> CardAttributesValueList { get; set; }               
}

public partial class CardAttributesValue
{        
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public System.String Value { get; set; }
}
```

WCF RIA Service:

```
public class CardService : DomainService
{
    //...

    [Query]
    public IList<Card> GetCardById(decimal cardId)
    {
        // return new card
    }

    [Update]
    public void UpdateCard(Card card)
    {
        // and save created entities
    }
}
```

I have to create on client a lot of new `CardAttributesValue` entities, then to save all of them.

The problem is that I always get "invalid changeset: child entity of type cannot be updated independent of its parent" error from wcf ria service.

How to handle with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `Composition` tag is your problem - that dicates that a `CardAttributesValueList` property can only be updated as part of a `Card` entity. If you want to be able to update it independently then remove the tag.

Comment: No, i want to save all new 'CardAttributesValue' entities in one transaction. That is, I mean that i want to save 'Card' with 'CardAttributesValueList' property.

Comment: Are you using the Composition tag elsewhere then? In your error you omitted what type is mentioned as not being able to "be updated independent of its parent". That error message is basically saying that you are trying to save some kind of entity when it has been declared as being a Composition of some other entity - and Composition entities can *only* be saved as part of a change to their parent.